# concatenation of two matrix emgu.cv. in c#

Tags: c#, machine-learning, emgucv, cross-validation

am working in c# with emgu, so my mission is to create svm model (maching learning  methode ) and test it using cross validation (divide the data in k folds / partitoin/ and use k-1 for train and 1 for test, loop for all partition ,for example k = 10 ; so in first loop , the first partition for the test and the rest for training , in second loop , the second partition for the test and ALL the rest for train .... and so on ) so, i should divide my data for each iteration.
the data is Matrix.
my problem was how to concatenation of two matrix. am trying to it with matrix.add(matrix)like as in this code  (just example to illustrate the problem):

```
   Matrix<int> cls = new Matrix<int>(5, 1);
   Matrix<int> cls1 = new Matrix<int>(6, 1);
   Matrix<int> cls2;
   cls.SetValue(1);
   cls1.SetValue(50);
   cls2=cls.Add(cls1);
   Console.WriteLine("fin {0}",cls2.Rows);
   Console.ReadKey(true);
```

my problem , the method add in matrix doesn't work. ??  it throw an exaption but no information my app crash,why and what should i do !

Answer (score 0):

after re-reading ALL the documentation of [matrix ( **Emgu.cv.**)](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/ec1c8c3f-a99c-a082-e794-bb74db961c60.htm) and googling and ... , i found that the method **add** doesn't add new rows or new cols to old matrix it is a addition val to val (+ mathimatique) so the correct method , there are two ConcateVertical and other horizintal wich, u can't found it in the web page of doc (it is a poor doc).